Finishing 2.76 version project, how to render the animation in object/material "viewport" mode in 2.7?
I am finally finishing a project I began years ago in 2.76.  Can anyone recall how to render out an animation in "object" mode rather than "render" mode?  The instructions for the new versions do not work with 2.76.  Thank you!!!

Was that option even available in such an early version? The option only appears in the Blender manual from version 2.80.

@JohnEason   It had to be available because I found animation image sequences in my temp folder that are viewport/object mode!  Unfortunately it's been so long since I worked on this, I have no idea how I made it happen.  Maybe I can bring these files into 2.8 just for this function?  I kinda thought I couldn't bring 2.7 files into 2.8.

I've no idea since it's so long since 2.7 was in use and I don't have it on my PC nowadays. There doesn't seem to be any mention of it in the 2.79 docs as far as I can see although I haven't searched thoroughly. You should be able to open 2.7 files in 2.8 (and even in version 4 although there may be some limitations).

@JohnEason I found it!  "OpenGL Render Animation" under "Render" at top of screen!  Thank you for responding!

Ah ok. Good luck!
